# How easily switch from simple view controller to tab bar controller?

Tags: ios6

I want to create main controller that will have four buttons, which will switch view if 
one is pressed. Problem is that I don't know how to implement this, probably there are
mistakes...
PS: new views are tab bar controllers

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: Yes, I'm using storyboards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the beginning I tried push method in my storyboard, but there was some mistake
that I don't know. Then I just tried modal and it's worked for me!